# Pillow conversion from RGB to indexed P mode

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an `RGB` image with only 25 colors,

[image]

and I want to convert it to `P` mode to make it indexed (saving space, as far as I understand), but the resulting image, though in `P` mode and indexed, has got 70 colors instead of 25:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> img = Image.open(r"test_rgb2p.png")
>>> img.mode
'RGB'
>>> len(img.getcolors())
25
>>> img = img.convert(mode='P')
>>> img.mode
'P'
>>> len(img.getcolors())
70
```

I guess that the `convert` command performs some kind of unnecessary resampling, because I see no reason why the number of colors should increment. In fact with GIMP I'm able to convert this same image to indexed colors and the number of colors does not change.

Is there a way to do this `RGB` to `P` mode conversion without changes in colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pillow has no idea that the number of colors in your image is restricted, so it must invent a palette that it thinks can handle everything.  You'll probably find that nearly none of those 70 colors is exactly identical to the colors in your image.

In fact if you look at the [documentation for `Image.convert`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) you'll see that it defaults to a web palette.  If you add `palette=ADAPTIVE` it might give better results:

```
img = img.convert(mode='P', palette=Image.Palette.ADAPTIVE)
```

Older versions of PIL/Pillow didn't have the `Palette` enumeration (I used 8.1.0 for this answer) and the constant is part of `Image` itself:

```
img = img.convert(mode='P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE)
```

Comment: Thanks, that allows to convert do `P` mode without changing the number of colors, although I guess that some unnecessary computation still happens, but at least the converted image should be identical to the original one. I admit that I did not read completely the documentation because I thought that the default behavior to follow was clear enough in case of images with less than 256 colors, but I was wrong.

Comment: You might want to complete your answer writing the code to obtain the seeked behavior: `img = img.convert(mode='P', palette=Image.Palette.ADAPTIVE, colors=len(img.getcolors()))`

Comment: @mmj `getcolors()` didn't work on a test image I tried, so I think it's best to leave it to figure out the best count on its own.

Comment: I know that `getcolors()` returns the number of colors only when there are less than 256 colors, otherwise returns `None`, maybe that's why it *didn't work* on you test image? Anyway I checked the command without the `colors=len(img.getcolors())` option and the returned image has the same identical 25 colors of original image, so I guess such option is not necessary. By the way, to get the number of colors of non indexed images with more than 256 colors you can use `len(set(img.getdata()))`.

Comment: @mmj how is `set(None)` going to help?  It fails for me.

Comment: `img.getdata()` shouldn't return `None`.

Comment: @mmj but it does for me.

Comment: Then you might have incurred in a Pillow bug.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
# Quantize the image to reduce the number of colors to 25
img = img.quantize(colors=25)

# Convert the image to P mode
img = img.convert(mode='P')

# Check the number of colors in the image
print(len(img.getcolors()))  # should print 25
```

This worked great for me at least!

Comment: This is clearly a possibility but is not a *real* solution, since it adds more unnecessary computations and does not guarantee that the resulting image is identical to the original one. Changing image mode, in the case described in my question, it's just a matter of changing data structure (i.e. of how image information are saved), should not affect image content in any way and should not involve computations like resampling or quantization.